# Pandas Spread DF to Indicator DF

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this

```
import pandas as pd

test = pd.DataFrame(data={"IDX": [0,0,0,1,1,2], 
                          "VAL": [27,5,13,27,24,13]})

   IDX  VAL
0    0   27
1    0    5
2    0   13
3    1   27
4    1   24
5    2   13
```

And want to spread it so the IDX becomes the columns, VAL becomes the rownames and the actual values are just indicators for whether the value is absent/present, like so:

```
out = pd.DataFrame(data={"0": [1, 1, 0, 1],
                         "1": [0, 0, 1, 1],
                         "2": [0, 1, 0, 0]}, index=[5, 13, 24, 27])

    0  1  2
5   1  0  0
13  1  0  1
24  0  1  0
27  1  1  0
```

Is there any way to do this efficiently without for-loops?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html) with `max`:

```
df = pd.get_dummies(test.set_index('VAL')['IDX'].sort_index()).max(level=0)
print (df)
     0  1  2
VAL         
5    1  0  0
13   1  0  1
24   0  1  0
27   1  1  0
```

Another solution - create lists per groups and then use [`MultiLabelBinarizer`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer.html):

```
s = test.groupby('VAL')['IDX'].apply(list)
print (s)
VAL
5        [0]
13    [0, 2]
24       [1]
27    [0, 1]
Name: IDX, dtype: object

from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer

mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
df = pd.DataFrame(mlb.fit_transform(s),columns=mlb.classes_, index=s.index)
print (df)
     0  1  2
VAL         
5    1  0  0
13   1  0  1
24   0  1  0
27   1  1  0
```

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Use `get_dummies`. See @jezrael's answer. Corrected my use of `crosstabs` below.

`pd.crosstab` will do the trick (if we make a slight modification)

`pd.crosstab(index=test['VAL'], columns=test['IDX'])`

```
IDX  0  1  2
VAL         
5    1  0  0
13   1  0  1
24   0  1  0
27   1  1  0
```

Since `crosstab` counts values and does not create indicators like `get_dummies` if we wanted to use `crosstabs` we would have to select all values above 0 and assign them to 1.

```
In [76]: test = pd.DataFrame(data={"IDX": [0,0,0,0,0,1,1,2], 
    ...:                           "VAL": [27,27,27,5,13,27,24,13]})
    ...:                           
    ...:                           
    ...:                           

In [77]: pd.crosstab(index=test['VAL'], columns=test['IDX'])
Out[77]: 
IDX  0  1  2
VAL         
5    1  0  0
13   1  0  1
24   0  1  0
27   3  1  0 <----------- IDX 0 VAL 27 = 3

In [78]: cross_tab = _

In [79]: cross_tab[cross_tab > 0] = 1

In [80]: cross_tab
Out[80]: 
IDX  0  1  2
VAL         
5    1  0  0
13   1  0  1
24   0  1  0
27   1  1  0 <---------- Back to a 1
```

Comment: Solution is wrong, working only with sample data. Problem is `crosstab` count data, not create indicator